# Project import of old firebase to new firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

The Google docs say that I should be able to see all my old firebase projects in the new console and then import them.

The problem is that 2 of the projects on the old firebase simply do not show up in the new console and therefore I cannot import them!

The two projects are in fact already using Google Cloud (for authentication) and I see can the projects listed when I click the "Import Google Project" button in the dropwdown. However, in that same dialogue window it says "add firebase to a Google Project", but there is already firebase included in the code for these projects (Android), so I am afraid this will screw things up?

I have a lot of live users on this Android app and trial/error by pressing this is not an option if it screws things up.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I seems I had the limit of 10 Google Cloud projects (the standard limit I think), and since Firebase actually uses Google Cloud as well, then I had to delete some old Google Cloud projects I did not use anymore.
Then my old firebase projects showed up in the new Firebase console and I could import them into the new console.